# Express Checkout token was issued for a merchant account other than yours

Tags: paypal, paypal-ipn, express-checkout

I am building a PayPal Express Checkout integration where buyer can send payments to sellers, so I specify the recipient not as myself but as

```
SUBJECT=seller@domain.com
```

It works and according to notifications in the sandbox, the payments are received. But when I try to do a `GetExpressCheckoutDetails` it shows the following error:

```
Express Checkout token was issued for a merchant account other than yours.
```

Is that normal? Is there any way around it so that I can still get the details? Or should I be notified with IPN instead.

Comment: Can you provide the complete response that you received from the PayPal including correlation id while calling GetTransactionDetails?